# Maven does not resolve correct SNAPSHOT dependencies

Tags: java, maven, dependencies, artifactory

I will be quick.  My maven version is 3.5.0. I'm using some libraries in my web applications. The libraries are installed separately and deployed in an artifactory instance.

I have the following pom (part of):

```xml
<project>
  ....
  <properties>
    <process.domain.common.version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</process.domain.common.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.intersoft</groupId>
        <artifactId>process.domain.common</artifactId>
        <version>${process.domain.common.version}</version>
      </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.intersoft</groupId>
      <artifactId>process.domain.common</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

but in the libs, Maven puts this library:

process.domain.common-0.0.1-20190319.151024-3.jar

instead of this:

process.domain.common-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar

My dependencies are resolved from artifactory. Why does Maven put this temporary library with timestamp name instead of the SNAPSHOT? This behavior does not happen in all resolved libraries.

Comment: is it possible that you have version "0.0.1-20190319.151024-3" somehow hardcoded as a transient dependency. That would in my opinion be the only reason why Maven would download it instead of the specified one. Did you completely clean your local environment before building (remove all previously downloaded libraries)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, i found the solution.

The solution is to add maven war plugin in your pom.xml of the war project:

```
<properties>
   <version.war.plugin>2.5</version.war.plugin>
</properties>

<build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${version.war.plugin}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warName>${project.artifactId}</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Proof:

WEB-INF/lib without the war plugin:
[image]

WEB-INF/lib **with** the war plugin:
[image]

Comment: Did the version 2.5 make the difference? Or did you just add the <plugin> snippet in order to solve your problem?

Comment: just added the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Maven append the current date to snapshots for compare the snapshot version from your local repository and the snapshot version from remote repository and evaluate if is required download remoting jar, because that downloading 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT today might give a different file than downloading it yesterday or tomorrow.

Comment: Do you have an official link that supports this? I've worked with Maven and never noticed that. Moreover, following your logic and the fact that the timestamp appended goes all the way to seconds, if I do a build every minute, then every minute a new version should be downloaded, irrelevant if it changed or not. That just doesn't seem right....

Comment: Understood. But the question is, why maven is putting in the war this unofficial version of the file, instead of the normal one.

Comment: @Theodore looks like you are running mvn with snapshots locked try run mvn versions:unlock-snapshots to use snapshot instead of timestaped version

Answer (score 0):

If you build a Snapshot locally, it is just build with the name `0.0.1-SNAPSHOT`. If you deploy it to Artifactory, it gets an internal timestamp version number like the one you mentioned.

When you download it again, Artifactory gives you the latest timestamp.

So locally, you sometimes have a `-SNAPSHOT` version and sometimes a timestamp version. The exact rule how the artifact in the war is named is unclear to me, but whether you have timestamped version or not, you should be fine.